# How do Implement Animation on These Card

Tags: android

I have two cards. In this, first card hides second half card. When I click on first card then first card shows me in front and second should be in behind and when click on second card then first should be behind . I searched many links but I don't know which animation is used in this.In this Image when I Click on white card then brown card should be replaced with white card and white should be replaced with brown.

View Card Class

```
public class ViewCard extends AppCompatActivity {

CardView card1,card2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_card);
    card1 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card2);
    card1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cardtemplatefront1);
    card2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cardtemplatefront2);

    card1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            card1.bringToFront();

        }
    });
    card2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            card2.bringToFront();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_view_card"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
tools:context="com.android.bizecard.BizCard.ViewCard">

<include layout="@layout/header"></include>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="390px"
        android:background="@drawable/cardtemplatefront1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="390px"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cardtemplatefront2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please post your xml code, and if you are having relative layout as parent of this cards you can use this property it might help.

```
cardView.bringToFront();
```

on click of the card

Comment: I need to animation. when click on card then card will be replace with animation not instant.

Comment: if you want to use default android animations just add 
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
on your parent view in xml file.

Comment: I want to Circular animation when i click first card then second should be come in front but in Circular animation

Comment: you can use objectAnimator you can refer this document
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html